# HTML - aligning image on the footer

Tags: html, css, image, alignment, footer

I'm having trouble trying to align my image to the bottom of the page. I'm editing my worpdress php files: footer.php for the html and stylesheet.css for the css. When I change the bottom dweller or the wrapper height it doesnt change the position of the image. How do I change the html/css so that it sits at a certain point at the bottom of the page?

**HTML**

```
 <div id="wrapper">
         <div id="bottomDweller">
         <img src="http://anbhialann.ie/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Menu-Pages-Badge.png" alt="Bottom of the page" width="42" height="42"></div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {height: 500px; position:relative;}
#bottomDweller {position: absolute; bottom:20px;}
```

Comment: show your code in issue with HTML along with a jsFiddle link

Comment: @davidfinlay : it is sitting at the bottom => http://jsfiddle.net/e34HY/ ....`bottom:20px` is doing its work, remove it for absolute base!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Like this

`remove` `bottom:20px` in below `#bottomDweller` ;

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/N4qWx/)**

**css**

```
#bottomDweller {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color:red;
}
```